# downloading image file from sql database using Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-boot-admin

In my project, I need to fetch data from SQL database and store it to a table.
I am able to fetch all the data except the image files. So I have now
the path

`image.path.idProofPhoto=/opt/static/images/idProofPhoto`

I need to fetch data from there

ok now what I did

I had to fetch the data as a format like `"id_imagename.jpeg"`
where `id` and `JPEG` are from the data stored in the database and id the id of employee and jpeg is the extension name of that file is also stored.
now I fetched the id and the extension now my file is something like `"1536_alex.jpeg"`
In this name, the file is in our database and the path is
`image.path.idProofPhoto=/opt/static/images/idProofPhoto`

So now my problem is how can I get those images and how to display?

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring image resource to serve images. I would suggest not to serve content from the local server location instead follow below approach.

1. Use CDN url/ Cloud bucket storage URL to serve this image content with pre-signed limited expiry for the URLS.
2. This will make your image to render really quick and avoid single point of failure also it will be you lifecycle management for your images.
3. Store and retrieve image URL's from your database. Create a new column and save image path mostly with some random image links, just to avoid guessing of the URL's. Don't create URL's which are guessable as anybody can guess and create URL to retrieve content.

If you have internal application where you can't host it on cloud then you can use Spring boot then refer to this http://zetcode.com/springboot/serveimage/

Comment: Its not on local repository. It's on the cloud database.

Comment: Yes above solution will work for both. See my answer below I have made some changes about saving Image URL as well.